# How to remove spaces from LinearLayout view inside Scrollview

Tags: android

[image: Without ScrollView][image]I want to scroll down my list.My list include **Linear layout**. Each Linear Layout include 2 or three image view horizontally. But there comes spaces between Linear Layouts while using **scroll view**. If i add more Linear Layouts that space comes between the vertical Linear Layouts. How we can remove that.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/face" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/face" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/face" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/face" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/line" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There are many LinearLayouts in your view, we don't know which one you're talking about. Please use id's to refer to your layouts or add some screenshots.

Comment: remove android:weightSum="4" from first linear layout

Comment: @Lakhan there are 4 Linear layouts thats y I set the :weightSum="4"

Comment: @Rami I have edit complete layout. Kindly copy and past in in you layout you will see spaces between Linear Layout. If you remove ScrollView then spaces remove.

Comment: @Tarikhelian I've copied your code and sorry there is no spaces. Maybe there is some transparent in your images borders and you think thats a space, try  to add colors as background of your LinearLayout, to be sure about that.

Comment: @Rami there is no transparency in images . I have upload my screen shot

Comment: @Tarikhelian the purple is the background of your first ImageView?

Comment: @Rami yes purple is the background of first ImageView,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `LineaLayout`, there is no space between them.

This is an explanation for your problem:

[image]

As you can see, your icon don't fit the size of the `ImageView`, so this is why you have the white space.

**To solve that:**

*Option1:*

You can add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute to your `ImageView` tag, but this may mess up your icon if width-height of the `ImageView` is bigger than icon size. Or give a try with **9.png** format icons, maybe it will do the trick.

*Option2:*

Use a fixed `width` and `height` for your `ImageView`.

Comment: But when you remove ScrollView from the layout then spaces removed as above uploaded screenshot.

Comment: It Means ScrollView do something wrong with the Linearlayout.

Comment: As you can see in your screenshot, the white space was reduced but  not completely disappeared. I don't know why it look different with ScrollView but i'm sure that ScrollView have no relation with the main reason. Try with a bigger device screen size (eg 10")  and you'll see that the space will appear again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `ScrollView` `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
....

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happening as you are using weights for your linear layouts or one of your images (whatsapp,face or line) might have some transparent area top and bottom of that.
Try to avoid weights as they decreases your layout performance.Weights causes  a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.